# AWS使用時のIPアドレスはNAT変換は必要でしょうか

Tags: aws

AWSにてEC2を利用し、サーバーを1台構築します。
オフィスのサーバと業務上のやり取り、およびクライアント数台からメンテ作業のため、アクセスを行います。
AWSとオフィスはインターネットVPNで接続予定です。

EC2のサーバーに割り振るIPアドレスは、オンプレで使用するIPとかぶらないものを割り振ることが推奨されているとネットに記載されていました。

この環境の場合、AWS上のサーバーに割り振るIPはプライベートIPになるのでしょうか。
それともグローバルIPでしょうか。

あるいは、AWS側・オフィス側どちらもプライベートIPで、VPN上の通信のためにグローバルIPを一つ用意するのでしょうか。
その場合、NAT変換等が必要ですか。

ネットワーク周りは初心者なうえ、クラウド利用時の一般的な考え方が不明なため質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

インターネットVPNがサイト間VPN（site-to-site VPN）だと仮定しての回答です。

IPアドレスは以下のようになるはずです。

- AWS上のサーバ：プライベートIPアドレス
- オフィスのサーバ：プライぺートIPアドレス
- オフィスのVPNルータ：パブリックIPアドレス　※Customer GatewayとしてAWS上に登録します。

NAT変換はAWSとオフィスでCIDRが重複していなければ不要なはずです。
(NAT変換が必要な場合、マネージドサービスがなかった気がするので自前で頑張る必要があると思います。もしかしたら、[VPN-トラフィック用に NAT を設定する](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-nat-for-vpn-traffic/)、とか参考になるかもしれません)

AWSとのサイト間VPNだと以下のページとかが分かりやすいのではないかと。
[自宅とAWSをVPN接続してみた ｜ DevelopersIO](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/shibata-rtx830-create-vpn-site/)
[自宅とAWSをVPN接続してみた (Ciscoルータ編) ｜ DevelopersIO](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/aws-cisco-site-to-site-vpn/)

※余談ですが、最近はClient VPNもできるようになったそうです（よく知らないのですが、用途によってはこちらのほうがよいのかもしれません）
[[AWS]踏み台をワンチャンなくせる！？VPC接続にClient VPNを使ってみよう ｜ DevelopersIO](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/vpc-client-vpn/)

Comment: なんとなく、 AWS 側にも public IP はあるんじゃないかな、と思っています (でないと、 site-to-site な VPN は張れないのではないか、、的な)